# How to optimize more than 3 objective functions on MATLAB? gamultibj is not efficient

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using MATLAB gamultiobj optimization 
as I have 6 to 12 objective functions; the gamultiobj function inefficiently handling the problem, always terminated because the number of generations exceeded, not because the changes of the objective functions become smaller
I looked at the gamultiobj options documentations, but it didn't help
http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/multiobjective-genetic-algorithm-options.html
1- how can I increase the capability of gamultiobj function to handle this number of objective functions?
2- are there a better way at all (using MATLAB)?

Answer (score 1):

Well,
this is my update:
1- I increased the number of generations, the population size, and assigned proper initial population using the common ga options, it worked better (I didn't know that they are working with gamultiobj too, but I knew, it isn't stated anywhere in the documentation explicitly).
2- after running and inspecting the results I realized that gamultiobj can handle many objective functions efficiently providing that they are independent. As long as the objective functions are strongly dependent (which is the case of my problem, unfortunately) the gamultiobj solver's efficiency dramatically decreases.
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the number of generations, possibly play with the options such as crossover, mutation, the constraint bounds in which you're going to get the solution. 
The bounds are to specified correctly. and the initial population is also pretty much needed to get it to the correct set of parameters that you want to optimize